How to shorten zip_close?
I'm using libzip v1.8.0 to compress files in my application. Somehow, the zip_close(..) function takes too long to complete. For instance, it takes ~3 minutes to compress 10 files each 32MB.
Below is the corresponding section of my code.
int err = 0;
auto const pZipHandler = ::zip_open(zipPath.c_str(), ZIP_CREATE | ZIP_TRUNCATE, &err);
if (!pZipHandler) {
    PLOGE << "Failed to create a new zip file: " << zipPath;
    PLOGD << fmt::format("Error code: {}, error: {}", err, zip_strerror(pZipHandler));
    PLOGD << "Recordings can still be found in " << recordFolderPath;

    return C2_ERROR_FAILED;
}

for(const auto &entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(recordFolderPath)) {
    if(entry.is_regular_file()) {
        const std::string filePath = entry.path().string();
        const std::string fileName = entry.path().filename().string();

        auto const pZipSource = zip_source_file(pZipHandler, filePath.c_str(), 0, 0);
        if (!pZipSource) {
            PLOGE << "Failed to create zip source for file: " << filePath;
            zip_close(pZipHandler);

            return C2_ERROR_FAILED;
        }

        if (zip_file_add(pZipHandler, fileName.c_str(), pZipSource, ZIP_CM_STORE) < 0) {

            PLOGE << "Failed to add file to zip: " << filePath;
            zip_source_free(pZipSource);
            zip_close(pZipHandler);

            return C2_ERROR_FAILED;
        }
    }
}

if(const auto retCode = zip_close(pZipHandler); 0 != retCode) {
    PLOGE << "Failed to close zip file: " << zipPath;
    PLOGD << fmt::format("Error code: {}, error: {}", retCode, zip_strerror(pZipHandler));

    return C2_ERROR_FAILED;
}

If you wonder, below is an example list of files I tried to compress.
root@machine:~# ls -lh /tmp/recordings_1637345115/
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2000000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2001000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2002000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2003000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2004000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2005000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2006000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2007000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2008000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2009000KHz-0.bin
-rw-rw-rw-    1 root     root       32.0M Nov 19 18:05 IQ-2010000KHz-0.bin

EDIT: Here is some additional info after the comments.

This is an embedded Linux system.
Both the application and the library are optimized.
zip command line utility performs similar.
The time consumption is nearly linear, it takes ~35s for two files of 32MB size.
Main storage write speed is ~10MB/s.


Hi. Did you profile your application? Is the speed restricted by I/O speed?

are you using compiler optimisations?

Is it a linear problem?  In other words, if you just compress one file is it 3 min/10? If not, it could indicate an I/O bottleneck

@AlanBirtles The application is compiled in release mode (-O3 -g0). Is there any other optimization that could potentially affect the situation?

Is the library optimised too?

@KamilCuk How can I do it? I'm on an embedded Linux system. Is there any good tool for that?

An embedded system with what characteristics? What’s the file system medium?

@DaveNewton The filesystem is on an SD card with a speed that won't affect the zipping process. I've got 2GB of physical RAM with 4-core ARM Cortex A53.

@edtheprogrammerguy ~40s for two files of the same size.

What timing results do you see on a command line: e.g. something like time zip archive.zip IQ-*KHz-0.bin?

I'm on an embedded Linux system. What "embeeded linux" exactly? "Embedded" is such an open term, are you on OpenSTLinux ? Bottom line, yes, profiling depends on the environment you are executing in. Can you share what specific environment are you working with? What is the cpu architecture? Kernel version? Available tools (GNU coreutils?) (bash?)? Are you using gcc - it supports https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html , and you could collect called functions and times and check, requires some work.

You might be also interested in ptrace strace times valgrind callgrind

@G.M. Nearly the same. That result scared me a bit as I thought the cause would not be related to software.

A couple things to keep in mind: while in the presence of enough memory it's possible to compress files in parallel for a .zip file, libraries usually don't do this, and the "usual" compression algorithm (deflate) itself is fundamentally single-threaded. zip_close unlikely has anything to do with the speed here.

@AlanBirtles Yes, the library is optimized as well.

Embedded processors are likely to be very slow.  Before I benchmarked mine I guessed it would be about 10x slower than my PC, it turned out to be 40x slower.

ZIP_CM_STORE does not do any compression. So you are completely I/O bound.

You sure it’s not the SD interface? It’s not just the card that matters.

@DaveNewton Following command takes ~27s to execute. dd if=/dev/urandom of=speedtest.bin bs=1K count=262144 oflag=direct. That means the writing speed is ~9.7MB/s

First identify the bottleneck: either the filesystem or the library.
Create a ramfs, copy your data there, and test compressing from the ramfs to the ramfs.
If the results are as bad, the library implementation / optimization / or inadequation to the platform or data is to blame. If it goes really faster (I doubt it), you can compress to ramfs and copy (asynchronously) after to the SD.
But as you are compressing what looks like IQ radio data, which probably is not very well compressible - by zip, I would recommend testing more suitable and tunable compressors like gz/xz. Or even lossy ones.
